# Angular 7 template isn't filling up the whole page

Tags: css, angular, angular7

So I am trying to convert this html page into my angular project. It works fine, but when I go to angular, it doesn't fill up the whole page. Here is a stackblitz example, this is what I see.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y8tdkt

Run the angular preview in a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In your code you are setting the body to display flex, this is causing the issue, if you remove the `display: flex` of `body` where ever you are setting this the screen will fill entirely, in regards to height.

I cant quite seem to see where you are setting it, but to show that it is this, add the following to see the screen in full height. (in `style.css`).

```
body {
  display: unset!important;
}
```

---

**Edit - found issue**

Found it in (`style.css`) line 9622, this is causing your issue.

```
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
  word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
}
```

The `display: flex` in here, remove it, and the page not filling up will not longer be a problem.

Comment: This fixed it, but am going to do more testing. To ensure if thats okay. Then I will mark it as the answer

Comment: thank you , be sure not to define css classes twice where it can be helped as things like this may occur :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have col-md-6 with a owl carousel in the left side.

change that to col-md-3 and the hello world col-md-6 will be in center in the fullscreen.

[image: fixed-image]

Comment: The hello isn't supposed to be in the center, there is a slide show on the left

Comment: I thought it was there by accident. It's empty. so thought that way. as JB Nizet mentioned, d-lg-block caused it to show only on desktop displays.

Comment: Yeah no, there is 2 sides too it. New to stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Well, your main section contains

```
<div class="col-md-6 d-none d-lg-block">...</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 h-100">...</div>
```

So, once the screen becomes large enough, the first div which was not displayed because of `d-none` becomes displayed because of `d-lg-block`, and the page thus becomes split in half.

Comment: That screen has 2 sides, left for slide show and right for user input. I just want to know why the page, isn't filling up.

Comment: "the page isn't filling up" is not very precise. What precisely do you expect to be displayed, where, and why?